# Deleting periodically repeating duplicated cells

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I'm having problems deleting duplicated cells in the following worksheet.
Col E are the hours and col F are the minutes from the timestamp, that I would like to organize. What I would like to do is delete all the rows containing duplicated minutes in an hour, so I can get readings for my current and power every 5 minutes. The problem being is, that sometimes you get 5 and sometimes 6 readings in a minute (because the readings were made every 9, 10, or 11) seconds. The other problem is, that I can't simply delete all the duplicated cells for one day, as the pattern repeats it's self every hour, thus leaving me with readings for only one hour, if I simply selected all cells.

What I'm trying in the code bellow is deleting all rows with double minute values within an hour by double clicking the first "E" cell, where that hour first appears. It works as it should for the first hour (0:00-0:55), but for later numbers (hours) it starts deleting additional rows.
The next logical step, would be ofcourse deleting all double values for one day.

The whole thing doesn't need to be user friendly or interactive, I just want to filter out the 5 minute reading and if nothing else, paste them onto a new worksheet for further analysis.

Here's a [printscreen](http://shrani.najdi.si/?2k/oN/4lnO8zQR/untitled.jpg) of the worksheet, containing the data

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim clickedRow As Long
Dim clickedValue As Long
Dim currentValue As Long
Dim counter As Long

clickedRow = ActiveCell.Row
clickedValue = ActiveCell.Value

For i = clickedRow To (clickedRow + 100)
    currentValue = Range("E" & i).Value
    If (clickedValue = currentValue) Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & clickedRow, "Y" & counter).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=6, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Another thing I tried, which didn't prove effective, as it hid all the duplicated cells, without leaving one out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim clickedRow As Long
Dim clickedValue As Long
Dim currentValue As Long
Dim zadnja As Long
Dim trenutna As Long

clickedRow = ActiveCell.Row
clickedValue = ActiveCell.Value

For i = clickedRow To (clickedRow + 100)

    currentValue = Range("E" & i).Value

    If (currentValue = clickedValue) Then

        zadnja = 5
        trenutna = Range("F" & i).Value

        If (trenutna = zadnja) Then
            Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
        End If

        zadnja = trenutna

    Else
        Exit For
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that Excel's remove duplicates function won't work for you, but can you please explain why so I can better understand how to help?

Comment: No it won't, because in the minutes column "F" the values 0, 5, 10,..., 55 repeat themselves each 5 to 6 times each hour. Here's another printscreen for hour values of 1: http://shrani.si/f/43/TU/1UedFbE2/untitled1.jpg

Comment: Please excuse me, as I'm new to the community, but is there a way, that i could upload the whole Worksheet? I already encountered some problems when trying to post pictures. Thanks

-Edit: I uploaded the Worksheet to Google Drive, you can view it at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWlcx6eE4TbcENDU3VOVjVZalk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Would it be easier for you to use a single column for both the hour and minute? Something like the [CEILING function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0A5CD7C8-0720-4F0A-BD2C-C943E510899F) or [FLOOR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14BB497C-24F2-4E04-B327-B0B4DE5A8886) could round to a 5 minute interval. e.g. `=FLOOR(C2, TIME(0, 5, 0))`.

Comment: Jeeped, not sure if that would work. I intentionally seperated the two so that values of both of them could be compared seperately. If you maybe have an example of the functions use for a similair problem, I'd be glad to check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) you need to take both the hour and the minute into consideration. Currently you are only basing the duplication criteria on the minute (e.g. Columns(6)).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Columns(5), Columns(6))) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Dim xlOriginalCalculation As Long, fr As Long, er As Long, tr As Long
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        xlOriginalCalculation = Application.Calculation
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        tr = Target.Row
        fr = Application.Match(Cells(tr, 5).Value, Columns(5), 0)
        If Target.Column = 6 Then
            fr = fr + Application.Match(Cells(tr, 6).Value, Cells(fr, 6).Resize(1440, 1), 0) - 1
            er = fr + Application.CountIfs(Columns(5), Cells(tr, 5).Value, Columns(6), Cells(tr, 6).Value) - 1
        Else
            er = fr + Application.CountIfs(Columns(5), Cells(tr, 5).Value) - 1
        End If

        If fr <> er Then
            With Range("A" & fr & ":Y" & er)
                .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 6), Header:=xlNo
            End With
            With Range("A:Y")
                .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(5), order1:=xlAscending, _
                            key2:=.Columns(6), order2:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlOriginalCalculation

End Sub
```

That removed duplicates based on both the hour and minute so that minute 55 in hour 0 is not confused with minute 55 in hour 1.

If MINS column (column F) is double-clicked then the data is deduped according to the minute. If the HRS column is double-clicked all of that hour's data is deduped.

There is no need for [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) with a worksheet codesheet.

Comment: Jeeped, thank you for your answer. We're almost there: now when I double click on an hour, next to a given set of minutes, it deletes the duplicated minutes. What I would like, to speed up the process is, when a cell containing a given hour is double clicked (example: 1), then we are only left with 1:05, 1:10,..., 1:55. I'm going to try using a for loop, I'll post back if I have any success

Comment: I tryed putting the second of the if sentences (the inner one) into a for loop and at the end of the loop increasing fr = fr + 1 and calculating er = fr + App...(as above), but the result is the same. 
Essentially we want to first: delete the duplicated cells, second: sort the cells, third: move onto the next row and repeat the first two steps.

Comment: Rather than permanently deleting the other records, wouldn't it be better to filter on the hour and just *show* 01:00, 01:05, 01:10, etc?

Comment: That would also be a possibility. But as I said, I can't get it to work with a for loop (to go through all the hours)

Comment: I've added a condition that if it is the HRS column that is double-clicked then all of that hour's data gets deduped.

Comment: Works like a charm! This will prove itself indispensable for my project. Thanks again Jeeped